# es2csv error out = {field: hit[field] for field in META_FIELDS} if self.opts.meta_fields else {}

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using es2csv and I am getting an error.I do have a query that works from curl. So I know that this is not related to the query. I passed the same query to curl and I am passing to es2csv

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/es2csv", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('es2csv==5.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'es2csv')()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 572, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2769, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2422, in load
return self.resolve()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2428, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/es2csv.py", line 209
out = {field: hit[field] for field in META_FIELDS} if self.opts.meta_fields else {}
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


es2csv -u http://10.x.x.x:9200 -o testinges2csv.csv -m 12000 -s 1000 -i abc_latest -D sbc  -r -q @'~/query string queryes2csv.json' -k -f aggregations.distinct_abc_UUID.doc_count_error_upper_bound
```

based on the es2csv syntax from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/es2csv/5.2.1#downloads). I cannot tell what the syntax error is. Note that I could not tag es2csv and so I am tagging other related items.

Comment: This seems like a python error, what version of python and elastic client are you using?

Comment: python is 2.6  and I am using es2csv 5.2.1, the latest

Comment: Same issues: https://github.com/taraslayshchuk/es2csv/issues/8 https://github.com/taraslayshchuk/es2csv/issues/20

Answer (score 0):

try python 2.7
i'm experiencing the same issue right now, works with python 2.7 but not with 2.6.6 that i would require.

Comment: What do you think your answer provides to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install 2.7 and use it in a virtualenv to solve this problem